# Selenium only loading JavaScript and not full HTML - Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, element

I am trying to find the search bar in this link: https://www.takealot.com using the class "search-field" from:

```
    input class="search-field " type="text" placeholder="Search for products, brands..." value=""
```

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.takealot.com/")

print(driver.page_source)

time.sleep(100)

driver.quit()
```

I have set sleep to 100 hoping that the HTML was taking long to load but I only seem to get the below output:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en"><head>
<link rel="preload" href="https://shopfront.takealot.com/static/js/app-loader.js" as="script">
<link rel="preconnect" href="//media.takealot.com" crossorigin="">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://shopfront.takealot.com" crossorigin="">
<link rel="preconnect" href="//api.takealot.com" crossorigin="">
<link rel="preconnect" href="//static.takealot.com" crossorigin="">
<title>Takealot.com: Online Shopping | SA's leading online store</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.takealot.com/favicon.ico?20110717" type="image/x-icon">
<meta property="twitter:account_id" content="4503599630296419">
<meta name="description" content="South Africa's leading online store. Fast, reliable delivery to your door. Many ways to pay. Shop anything you can imagine: TVs, laptops, cellphones, kitchen appliances, toys, books, beauty &amp; more. Shop the mobile app anytime, anywhere." data-react-helmet="true"><link rel="canonical" href="https://www.takealot.com/" data-react-helmet="true"><link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="https://m.takealot.com/" data-react-helmet="true"><link rel="alternate" href="android-app://fi.android.takealot/app/takealot.com/home" data-react-helmet="true"><meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" data-react-helmet="true"><meta property="og:site_name" content="Takealot.com" data-react-helmet="true"><meta property="og:title" content="Takealot.com: Online Shopping | SA's leading online store" data-react-helmet="true"><meta property="og:description" content="South Africa's leading online store. Fast, reliable delivery to your door. Many ways to pay. Shop anything you can imagine: TVs, laptops, cellphones, kitchen appliances, toys, books, beauty &amp; more. Shop the mobile app anytime, anywhere." data-react-helmet="true"><meta property="og:image" content="https://www.takealot.com/static/images/logo_transparent.png" data-react-helmet="true"><script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "https://www.takealot.com",
    "name": "Takealot.com",
    "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "https://www.takealot.com/all/?qsearch={search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
    }
  }
</script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<style>
        html, body {
          background-color: #f4f4f4;
        }
        .sf {
          min-height: 400px;
        }
      </style>
<link href="https://shopfront.takealot.com/56ef9861e86851c6e164b4f9ac61aaf391be03e0/static/js/runtime-752252ceefc11a26036e.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="https://shopfront.takealot.com/56ef9861e86851c6e164b4f9ac61aaf391be03e0/static/js/vendors~app-79405fe02e9a75a07916.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="https://shopfront.takealot.com/56ef9861e86851c6e164b4f9ac61aaf391be03e0/static/js/app-0aaac12d85774ebc557d.js" rel="preload" as="script"><script src="https://shopfront.takealot.com/56ef9861e86851c6e164b4f9ac61aaf391be03e0/static/js/runtime-752252ceefc11a26036e.js"></script></head>
<body id="body">
<div class="sf " id="shopfront-app"><style>
    @keyframes load-in {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    @keyframes load8 {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }

      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    .appload-wrapper {
      animation: load-in 200ms linear;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 300px;
      position: relative;
      transform: translateZ(0);
    }

    .apploader {
      animation: load8 .8s infinite linear;
      border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(77, 77, 79, .2);
      border-left: 3px solid #0b79bf;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-right: 3px solid rgba(77, 77, 79, .2);
      border-top: 3px solid rgba(77, 77, 79, .2);
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: block;
      font-size: 10px;
      height: 30px;
      left: calc(50% - 15px);
      position: absolute;
      text-indent: -9999em;
      top: calc(50% - 15px);
      transform: translateZ(0);
      width: 30px;
    }

    .apploader::after {
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="appload-wrapper">
      <div class="apploader"></div>
    </div></div>
<script src="https://shopfront.takealot.com/static/js/app-loader.js" onload="window.loadShopfront('https://shopfront.takealot.com');" type="text/javascript">
      </script>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the value in search field Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and use below css selector.

```
driver.get("https://www.takealot.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.search-field"))).send_keys("USB")
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

To learn more about `WebDriverWait` refer this link [ExplicitWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)